# Vector notation $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_{i}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ vs $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\right)$

Tags: notation

I've seen matrices defined as $\mathbf{X}=\left(x_{ij}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq m}$ and I wonder if it is customary to use an equivalent notation for vectors, i.e., $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_{i}\right)_{1\leq i\leq n}$, or even $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_{i}\right)$ if the dimension is clear from the context. I'd like to avoid the more cumbersome $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\right)$.

Comment: Yes, you can use that notation.